# address of entire row of 2 dimensional array in C - syntax

Tags: c, arrays, syntax, multidimensional-array, row

My question is related to the syntax used in plain C to address an entire row from a 2-dimensional array. So, if I have a 2d array like:

```
arr[rows][columns]
```

and I want to pass the address of an entire row from this array to a given function f, would a construction like:

```
f(&arr[i])
```

be okay in plain C? Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int arr[rows][columns];

void f(int *array) {
   int i; 
   for (i=0;i<columns; i++) {
      array[i] = 5 ; // as example
      ........
   }
}
```

and then you can called as mentioned in your question

```
f(&arr[i]);
```